# Combine a list of names with a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, combine

I have 2 dataframes :
Employees

```
Names
Bob
Jack
Jill
Fred
```

Hours :

```
Name mon tues wens thur fri
Bob   5         4    3
Jack       5    3        6
Fred  3    3    2    3   1
```

I can not figure out how to combine them

Im trying to get the result:

```
Name mon tues wens thur fri
Bob   5   nan   4    3  nan
Jack nan   5    3   nan  6
Jill nan  nan  nan  nan nan
Fred  3    3    2    3   1
```

I have tried to make the list of employees the same size as hours but it keep over writing it to get a dataframe full of nan is there a way to get the above result

Comment: Try: `df1.merge(df2, left_on='Names', right_on='Name', how='left')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` after `rename` the column of your first dataframe:

```
>>> Employees.rename(columns={'Names': 'Name'}).merge(Hours, how='left')
   Name  mon  tues  wens  thur  fri
0   Bob  5.0   4.0   3.0   NaN  NaN
1  Jack  5.0   3.0   6.0   NaN  NaN
2  Jill  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
3  Fred  3.0   3.0   2.0   3.0  1.0
```